# How to override Actions directory file of Laravel Voyager?

Tags: laravel-5.8, voyager

In Voyager for browse page actions column has following buttons:

Delete, View & Edit

Icon values for above buttons coming from getIcon() method used in respective action file stored at **/vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Actions/**

For example: Delete button icon value fetching from **/vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Actions/DeleteAction.php@getIcon**

Now I want to change this value without touching above file.

How would I override above file?

---

After some research I found below
By somehow I will have to override below file:

\vendor\tcg\voyager\Voyager.php

In above file DeleteAction is imported using below code:

use TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction;

Answer (score 3):

Create your own Action class, probably extending the original Voyager Action class:

`App\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Voyager\Actions;

use TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction as VoyagerDeleteAction;

class DeleteAction extends VoyagerDeleteAction
{
    public function getIcon()
    {
        return 'my-custom-icon';
    }
}
```

The replace the default Action with yours in your Service Provider:

`App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction as MyDeleteAction;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    ...

    public function boot()
    {
        ...

        Voyager::replaceAction(DeleteAction::class, MyDeleteAction::class);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You can see the [source of the `replaceAction()` method at [voyager]/src/Voyager.php:174](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.3/src/Voyager.php#L174)